# IsolatedStorge with Firefox

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I have following code to use IsolatedStorageFile:

```
IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
```

It is fine with IE, but when I run the app with FF, I got the error for this code:

Operation not permitted.

How to resolve it?

Comment: I have never encountered a Firefox specific bug with IsolatedStorage. Can you get the details about the exception?